# Can I alias a database name or create a synonym for a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to sync data from an on-premise SQL Server to an Azure SQL Server using Microsoft SQL Data Sync 2.0.   The problem is my database name has a . in it (MyDatabase.V2), this is not allowed.

Is there a way for me to have a secondary name for this database for the Sync tool to reference?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. Can you not quote your database name(I.e. `[MyDatabase.V2]`)? Generally, however, as you have found out, it is a bad idea to use special characters in an object's name. If you can rename the database, I would.

Comment: Yeah, 8 years into using this database, used in 100 connection strings - I am stuck with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not currently a possibility with SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Create an SQL Server job to back up `MyDatabase.V2` and restore it as `MyDatabaseV2`. Then, use this new `MyDatabaseV2` with Data Sync 2.0. Basically, a work-around. If you need more frequent data replication in the new `MyDatabaseV2`, look into log shipping or replication.